# Undefined reference to RosIntrospection functions

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I try to convert the Raw Buffer of a ShapeShifter to its original DataType Structure. But I have Problems understanding the new API. In the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_type_introspection/Tutorials/GenericTopicSubscriber) the author used functions, which are not available anymore, so I tried to do it with the latest headers available.

As I understand the new API, I have to register the MessageDefinition first and afterwards I can deserialize the Buffer IntoFlatContainer.

Copy of the [ros_type_introspection.hpp](https://github.com/facontidavide/ros_type_introspection/blob/master/include/ros_type_introspection/ros_introspection.hpp):
In the file is a short description to each function

```
  void registerMessageDefinition(const std::string& message_identifier,
                                 const ROSType &main_type,
                                 const std::string& definition);

  bool deserializeIntoFlatContainer(const std::string& msg_identifier,
                                    absl::Span<uint8_t> buffer,
                                    FlatMessage* flat_container_output,
                                    const uint32_t max_array_size ) const;
```

Here is my code:

using namespace RosIntrospection;

```
static std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
static FlatMessage flat_container;
Parser parser;    
const std::string& datatype   = msg->getDataType();
const std::string& definition = msg->getMessageDefinition();

ROS_INFO("datatype: %s", datatype.c_str() );

buffer.resize( msg->size() );
ros::serialization::OStream stream(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
msg->write(stream);


parser.registerMessageDefinition(datatype, ROSType("geometry_msgs/Twist"), definition);
```

The registration of the MessageDefinition fails. And functions like described in the wiki (e.g buildROSTypeMapFromDefinition) are not available anymore.

My current error message:

```
RosSender.cpp:(.text+0x3cc): undefined reference to `RosIntrospection::ROSType::ROSType(absl::string_view)'
RosSender.cpp:(.text+0x3ed): undefined reference to `RosIntrospection::Parser::registerMessageDefinition(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, RosIntrospection::ROSType const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

Can anyone tell me how to use the new API correctly to get the original message?

Thank you!!

edit (Add CMakeList.txt):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14")
project(RosSender)

set(THIRDPARTY_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../thirdParty)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)


catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS
  LIBRARIES RosAdapter
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}    
)
include_directories(
  ${THIRDPARTY_DIR} 
)


add_executable(RosSender src/RosSender.cpp)

target_link_libraries(RosSender ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}/oa/myOaLib.so)
target_link_libraries(RosSender /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libtopic_tools.so)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301009/undefined-reference-to-rosintrospection-functions/) by [Felix394](https://answers.ros.org/users/36852/felix394/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-20**:
The last error is a linker error, not something else.

So apparently the compiler is happy, but the linker can't find the specific symbol it needs to link your executable.

Are you enabling / using C++11 in your pkg and linking the `ros_type_introspection` libraries correctly?

**Comment by [Felix394](https://answers.ros.org/users/36852/felix394/) on 2018-08-20**:
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14")
these are my link libraries:
target_link_libraries(RosSender ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(RosSender /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libtopic_tools.so)
I don't have other *.so files to link

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-20**:
Please add this to your original question text. Comments are too limited.

re: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ..)`: don't do this. If you must use `set(..)`, use `set(VAR "new entry $VAR")` so as to not override whatever was already there.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-20**:
Can you please add your complete `CMakeLists.txt` to your question?

I don't understand why you're listing the absolute path to the `topic_tools` library like that.

**Comment by [Felix394](https://answers.ros.org/users/36852/felix394/) on 2018-08-21**:
I had to add the path, because otherwise I got Linking Problems

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-21**:
Could I refer you to [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt)? `topic_tools` is a Catkin pkg, so it should appear in your `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ..)` call.

There are some other unusual things in your `CMakeLists.txt` file as well.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-21**:
Fi: you have `DEPENDS system_lib` in there. But you never actually build a library called `system_lib`. If you don't intend to, remove the `DEPENDS system_lib` line.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-21**:
Could you also please use the *Preformatted Text* button when copy-pasting code/build scripts/console text? It's the one with `101010` on it. That would make things much easier to read.

Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-21**:
Final comment:

> In the wiki the author used functions, which are not available anymore

have you reported this to the author on his [issue tracker](https://github.com/facontidavide/ros_type_introspection/issues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but I don't see `ros_type_introspection` (ie: the Catkin package) appear anywhere in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

As you're using the package, I would expect it to appear at least in:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS .. ros_type_introspection ..)
```

and:

```
catkin_package(.. CATKIN_DEPENDS .. ros_type_introspection ..)
```

Linking against `catkin_LIBRARIES` should then allow the linker to resolve all used symbols.

---

Edit: the same goes for `topic_tools`. It's a Catkin package as well, so I would expect it to appear in the same places as `ros_type_introspection`.

---

Edit2: also don't forget to add the correct build and exec dependencies to your `package.xml`. See the [catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html) for how to do that.

---

Edit3: based on what you show us, I would expect to see a `CMakeLists.txt` like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(RosSender)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)

# this overrides the C++11 enabled before this line
add_definitions(-std=c++14)

# 'pretend' OaLib is a nice CMake findable pkg
# we don't bother with find_library et al. and shortcut things a bit
set(THIRDPARTY_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../thirdParty)
add_library(OaLib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET OaLib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${THIRDPARTY_DIR}/oa/myOaLib.so")


# rospy is not a build dependency, so can probably be removed here
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ros_type_introspection
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  topic_tools
)

# check order of include directories here
include_directories(
  ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

catkin_package(
  # you don't export any include directories, so this should be removed
  INCLUDE_DIRS
  # this library is not being built, so this line should be removed
  LIBRARIES RosAdapter
  # rospy should be removed here as well: it cannot be a build dependency
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs ros_type_introspection topic_tools
)

add_executable(RosSender src/RosSender.cpp)
target_link_libraries(RosSender ${catkin_LIBRARIES} OaLib)
```

I've added some comments above lines I can't be sure about, so check those yourself.

Linking static libraries like you did is not recommended, so I replaced it with an [imported target](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/Exporting-and-Importing-Targets).

And please note: this is all CMake, *not* Catkin or special to ROS.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix394](https://answers.ros.org/users/36852/felix394/) on 2018-08-21**:
I have never build a package ros_type_introspection, because I only have the header files from the git repo. Add it to the CMakeLists as package will throw an exception.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-21**:
`ros_type_introspection` is a ROS package. Just the header files are not enough to successfully use it.

If you are on Ubuntu, just do a `sudo apt install ros-$distro-ros-type-introspection`.

I cannot help you further without more information on your build environment (OS, versions, etc).

**Comment by [Felix394](https://answers.ros.org/users/36852/felix394/) on 2018-08-21**:
Ok shame on me, I was completely stumped staring at my monitor like wtf

**Comment by [Felix394](https://answers.ros.org/users/36852/felix394/) on 2018-08-21**:
Thank you so much !!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-21**:
Your question had me thoroughly confused, as I assumed you knew how to set this all up.

From #q299711 I had assumed (perhaps wrongly) that you were a bit more experienced with all this -- writing middleware bridges is not typically a task for first-timers.